# Integrate facebook into rating logic

Tags: social-network, rating

I want to build a functionality on my website that allows you to +1 (add a vote) a post.
I want to integrate this functionality with facebook, so that 1 single vote is allowed per facebook user (without creating an account for that user on my site -- if it is possible).

Please point me in the right direction for this.
I'm looking for any solution that is a Drupal Best Practice, or any idea that you have on the subject and how it can be achieved.

Right now I think I will go with [Fivestar](https://drupal.org/project/fivestar) module, but I'm not sure how to integrate this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for [Entity External Rating](https://drupal.org/project/entity_external_rating) module. Check the [site](http://fotobout.com/) using this module.

> This module can be used to implement a rating system based on external
>   sources. What that means is that the actual rating, voting or whatever
>   action, happens on an external application (for example on Facebook),
>   and the results are fetched into your system. By itself, this module
>   is intended for developers to use it like an API.

One key question would be why to use this module and not the Voting API with the **Fivestar module** for example. Here are the most important reasons:

- The main advantage of this module is that your system does not handle now the actual rating process. This now happens on external systems.
- You can have many sources from which your rating is fetched. The results will be aggregated from all of them.
- If you have a site with mostly anonymous traffic, it will be very easy for your users to rate content through **Facebook or Twitter**.

Comment: Can you elaborate how would this work? The workflow for this scenario.

Comment: check the readme.txt file everything mentioned there

Comment: I managed to test the module a bit, seems the right choice, thank you!